What movie or show has a guy who dies in a bathroom and the devil gives him another chance but has to kill people
I seen part of a movie where a guy dies in a bathroom from drinking but when he wakes up he’s dead and the devil is in front of him but he talked to the devil saying he’ll have another chance if he kills certain people within a certain amount of time but there was a girl that he went to high school with and was going to spike her drink but never killed her. 
Then he met up with his friend and told his friend the whole story and  his friend explains he had  the same experience and said that he only had to kill 1 person and that was him and he gave him a drink that made him foam out the mouth and die.
I don’t think it was a famous actor, It was about a year ago. I think it came out around 2007. It looks like US film.
